# Codeigniter, Access Certian are of website from other domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have created web application using codeigniter, where user can create their profile, resume, what I want is user can point their domain to their profile.

For example I have main base website www.example.com, where people can create their profile like www.example.com/user1, I want www.user1.com point to www.example.com/user1

I do not want to  : 
1. HTTP redirect 
2. I do not want to host all codeigniter code in user1.com (means at user1.com i dont want to host replica of example.com at user1.com )

Answer (score 0):

To point www.user1.com to another domain you need to add CNAME record 'www' pointing to www.example.com

OR

you can use javascript to redirect to  www.example.com/user1, in this case url will changed to www.example.com/user1.

Comment: This is not proper answer, as i said i dont want to redirect i want to point the domain

Comment: nileshv if you do not want redirect you need to change DNS records of www.user1.com as i said as first option

Comment: Dear I understand it, but you did not understand my question, with dns i can point domain user1.com to my server, but what exactly i want to do is when user1.com point to server it work as www.example.com/user1, the question is not related it to dns it is related to codeigniter